# Is running weighted sampling for twice different from for once?

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume we have $n$ positive numbers $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^n$, then  $\{w_i/\sum_{i=1}^nw_i\}_{i=1}^n$ can be used as sampling probabilities. 
Now, we sample with replacement from $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^n$ for $p$ times and get $q\leq p$ different numbers. We know that the probability of choosing $w_i$ is $w_i/\sum_{i=1}^nw_i$.

Let's say the above $q$ sampled numbers are $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^q$, then we use$\{w_i/\sum_{i=1}^qw_i\}_{i=1}^q$ as sampling probabilities and sample with replacement from $\{w_i\}_{i=1}^q$ for $p$ times. Then, the probability of choosing $w_j$ is still $w_j/\sum_{j=1}^nw_i$? $1\leq j\leq n$.

Comment: Do you intend thenumbers to be the same as the weights?  If your numbers are $1,2$ are we guaranteed that $1$ has probability $\frac 1{1+2}=\frac 13$ to be chosen?  Your notation implies this.  Then using $w_i$ for the sampled numbers is confusing.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The last sentence in the first paragraph is not correct.  The chance of choosing $w_i$ on any given sample is as you say, but that is not the chance of choosing $w_i$ at all.  As an example, if $n=3, w_1=1, w_2=2, w_3=3$ on any given draw we have $\frac 16$ chance of picking $1,$ $\frac 13$ chance of picking $2,$ and $\frac 12$ chance of picking $3$.  If $p$ is rather large we will have essentially chance $1$ to get all of $1,2$ and $3$ in our first sample.  Then your second draw is just like the first.  If $p=1$ we have just one element in the first sample and draw it in the second draw, getting the same probabilities.  However if $p=2$ the second draw is biased.  We have $\frac 1{36}$ chance of just having $1, \frac 19$ chance of having $1,2,$ and $\frac 16$ chance of having $1,3$ among others.  The chance we draw $1$ on the second draw is then $\frac 1{36}+\frac 13 \cdot \frac 19+\frac 14\cdot \frac 16=\frac{23}{216} \neq \frac 16$